# How i can set two conditions in one "if"?

Tags: android, if-statement

**How I can set two conditions in one "if", like:**

```
if (value  > 0 and value <3) {  

           }
```

Comment: How could value be both `== 0` and `> 3` at the same time?

Comment: i just wanted fast answer didn't thinked about the code you got the idea

Comment: *I just wanted fast answer* is not an excuse for not writing a decent question. If it's not worth your effort to ask the question properly, it's certainly not worth our effort to answer it.

Comment: well its fixed now u can answer it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `&&`. In java you can add to conditions instead of one by using `&&`. You most likely don't want to use `&` because it is a bitwise and. In order to use the logical and (`&&`) you write your if statement in the format of the following example:

```
if(condition1 && condition2){
System.out.print("both conditions are true");
} else {
System.out.print("at least one condition was false");
}
```

In conclusion, all you should need to do with your code you supplied with your question is to replace "and" with `&&`.